# Applying custom-security-filter to multiple flows in Mule configuration

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a mule application where there is login flow. The flow contains an http endpoint which takes user/password as form post parameter. Once the user/password is matched we create an auth token and store it in the database. And, then later send it in the login api response.

Now, I have multiple other flows in the same mule configuration file. Each of them represents a specific endpoint/api. Now I want to apply a custom-security-filter to all the flows apart from login endpoint flow.

One way is to keep adding the custom-security-filter component in each of the flows. I don't want to do that. Rather I want to mention it once that this security filter is applicable to all the flows apart from login flow.

Is that possible in Mule?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a choice and only apply authorization filtering if the request is not for your login endpoint. e.g.

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="[Is this a login request?]">
        <!-- Do nothing -->
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <!-- User must be authorized -->
        <mule-ss:authorization-filter doc:name="Authorize" 
            requiredAuthorities="ROLE_REQUIRED_AUTH" />
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This **choice** component can only be included inside a mule flow. And, in my case, each api is a different flow. So, are you asking me to put this **choice** component inside each flows? If not, then can you please elaborate more? What I want is to keep it in a global location one time and each flows doesn't have to include the same.